# Nested Switching Powershell to form user Groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking to automate User groups by Creating a list of Groups a user should be part of, based on 3 requirements, their branch, their department within that branch, and their Division. Divisions are National, while each Department depends on the Branch
so far I have this Broken Mess haha,

I had working separately the Branch and Division just using a switch and array(CODE NOT SHOWN), but they were mutually Exclusive so wouldn't work with the departments that need to change based of branch my attempt to nest these switches while also appending to an ArrayList appears to have failed spectacularly. not really sure where to go from here.

the end goal would be an output of a list of groups, that a user would then be added to.
any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

```
$csvFile = 'C:\Path'  # Enter a path to your import CSV file


Import-Csv -Path $csvFile | ForEach-Object {

    $User = $_.firstname
    $Branch = $_.Branch
    $Divison = $_.Division
    $Department = $_.Department
    $AllStaff = @(
        "All Staff"
        "Staff Wifi"
    )



    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$UserGroups = @()

    $UserGroups.add($AllStaff)

    Switch ($Branch) {
        "Christchurch" {

            Switch ($Department) {
                "ProServices" {
                    $UserGroups.Add("CHCH ProServices")

                }
                "Sales" {
                    $UserGroups.Add("Christchurch Sales")

                }
            }
            $UserGroups.Add("Christchurch Staff")
        }


        "Auckland" {
            Switch ($Department) {
                "ProServices" {
                    $UserGroups.Add("AKL ProServices")

                }
                "Sales" {
                    $UserGroups.Add("Auckland Sales")

                }
            }

            $UserGroups.Add("Auckland Staff")
        }

        "Wellington" {
            Switch ($Department) {
                "ProServices" {
                    $UserGroups.Add("Wellington ProServices")

                }

            }
            $UserGroups.Add("Wellington Staff")
        }

        "Dunedin" {
            Switch ($Department) {
                "ProServices" {
                    $UserGroups.Add("DUN ProServices")

                }
                "Sales" {
                    $UserGroups.Add("Dunedin Sales")

                }
            }
            $UserGroups.Add("Dunedin Staff")
        }
        Default {
        }
    }

    switch ($Division) {
        'Sales' {
            $UserGroups.Add("SalesStaff")
        }
        'internal Sales Support' {
            $UserGroups.Add("Internal Sales Support")
        }
        'Service' {
            $UserGroups.Add("Service Staff")
        }
        Default {
        }
    }
    write-host "$user ALL Groups Are $UserGroups"
    $UserGroups = @()
}
```

Comment: Not the answer but you may want to add `[Void]' in front of the `.add()` calls.  ArrayList's Add method will echo the index number of the element that's added.  This can cause issues as well as unwanted output.

Comment: so where does the [void] go? in the line? [void]$UserGroups.Add(). there ?

Comment: ah yes that works thanks, prevented the added numbers, the problem mentioned in the Answer below.

Comment: You got it.  you can up vote that comment if it was helpful...  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a spelling mistake in $Divison at the top. It doesn't match the call to $Division in the switch statement.

Also just try outputting the $UserGroups on a separate line, without "".

I got:

```
Bob ALL Groups Are System.Object[] CHCH ProServices Christchurch Staff SalesStaff
```

As the output when doing it your way rather than:

```
All Staff
Staff Wifi
CHCH ProServices
Christchurch Staff
SalesStaff
```

When outputting to it as not a string

Comment: `write-host "$user will be added to the following groups:"`
(then a new line, I hate the formatting in these comments)      
`$UserGroups`

Comment: oh, i thought you were talking about inside the switches, ah yes that looks much better now.

Comment: thanks for that , but im getting some numbers in the output that corresponds to how many Groups there are, so its all of separate lines, then there are more sperate lines stating at 0 corresponding to how many Groups there are. 
any idea how to get rid of that ?.
$user will be added to the following groups: (Newline)
All Staff (newline)
Staff Wifi(newline)
0(newline)
1(newline)
. I agree with your statement about comment formats.

Comment: That is weird. Looks like the numbers are coming from the maze of switch statements, not the output step. Can't see anything immediately. I'll have a look.

Comment: Its each of the $UserGroups.Add() which are outputting the numbers. Pipe them to Out-Null to suppress the output. e.g. 
`$UserGroups.add($AllStaff) | Out-Null`

Comment: Note: in versions prior to 7 `Out-Null` is quite slow.  I haven't tested it in 7 but some of the PowerShell devs told may they made major improvements.  At any rate in earlier versions like 5.1, which is still in heavy use. [Void] is the cleanest way to do it.  Some people think assigning to $null is even faster that [Void], that hasn't been my experience and I think the [Void] approach is more readable.